# JamVM NoClassDefFoundError when main is inside of a package

Tags: java, classpath, jamvm, gumstix

I am getting a NoClassDefFoundError, class file has wrong name, when I try to put HelloWorld in a package!  I am using Jamvm v1.5.2.  I am assuming my class paths are set correctly because I am able to run when HelloWorld is not in a package...  How do I get a main to run inside of a package with jamvm?  What path do I need to set for this to work?  Thanks.

Hello.java:

```
public class Hello 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello gumstix.");
    }
}
```

root@overo:~/default# jamvm Hello
Hello gumstix.

Hello.java:

```
package test.com;

public class Hello 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello gumstix.");
    }
}
```

root@overo:~/test# jamvm Hello
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Hello
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: class file has wrong name

Comment: try jamvm test.com.Hello

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you have `package test.com;`, but if you had `package test;` try moving the Hello.class file to a folder named "test" and then write

```
root@overo:~/default# jamvm test.Hello
```

from directory where yout "test" folder is.

Works on Windows with standart Java SE version, hope it will work for you too.